# Netlify cms change github name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify-cms

[image]
I have a project on netlify-cms. There are configured all the fields for entering content, and this content in the netlify-cms is visible, and with the help of graphQl I make a pull request but as soon as I change the user of the guthub in yaml file then when I go to the admin there all the fields need to be filled again. How to fix it?